# ng-change trigger event when ng pattern condition changes from true to false

Tags: angularjs

Problem:

`ng-change` is getting triggered when the pattern is changing from true to false.

Example:

pattern valid value is minimum 10 digits so when digits count changing from 9 to 10 ,event is fired which is correct. but if 1 digit is deleted then again event is fired. which should not happen or i might be missing something here.

My code is something like:

```
input id="id1" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required 
  ng-valid-pattern" type="text" ng-focus=""  
  ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{10,19}$/" required="" 
  ng-change="event1(Method1.id1)" ng-model="Method1.id1"
  placeholder="1234123412341*" 
  ng-class="{'active': !method21.id1.$pristine}" name="id1"
```

Does any one have solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This, the problem is `ng-change` function triger before the value change

```js
var jimApp = angular.module("mainApp",  []);

jimApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.Method1 = {};
  $scope.event1 = function(id){
    if(angular.isDefined(id)){
      alert(id);
    }
    
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <form>
    <input id="id1" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required 
  ng-valid-pattern" type="text" ng-focus=""  
  ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{10,19}$/" minlength="10" required 
  ng-change="event1(Method1.id1);" ng-model="Method1.id1"
  placeholder="1234123412341*" 
  ng-class="{'active': !method21.id1.$pristine}" name="id1">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not understanding the code portion you given for JS as i am completely new to Anjular js.Can you explain me something here ?

Comment: angular.isDefined function checks the value is defined or not